# Visual Studio not running / debugging code anymore

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2019

[image]

I am using Visual Studio 2019 with .NET extension .

Everything was working fine, i.e all my C# codes and projects were executing fine on F5 when suddenly the options went dead . I am farely new to Visual Studio and cant seem to get my head around this problem . If anyone can suggest anything , it would be of great help.

Comment: Did you face that `Start Debugging` and `Start Without Debugging` options are unchecked when you want to debug your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, 
Go to project properties -> Build Tab. Then click Advanced button on the right bottom corner of the pane. Change "Debug Info:" to "full" and click OK.

[image]

[image]

If it is like that, then change it to "full" like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Visual Studio not running / debugging code anymore

Please try these suggestions:

**Suggestions**

1. unload your current project by right-click on your project-->`Unload your project` and then close VS Instance, enter your project path, delete `.vs` hidden folder, `bin`, `obj` folder and then restart your project again.

   Then Upload the project, right-click on the project-->`set as startup project` to test.
2. reset VS settings by `Tools`-->`Import and Export Settings`-->`Reset all settings`
3. disable any other third party extensions under `Extensions`-->`Manage Extensions`
4. restart your VS and then rebuild your project
5. try to create a new empty default project and then test again whether the issue persists, if so, you should try to [do a repair in VS Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019), if not, I think the issue is related to your project itself.

Answer (score 0):

same issue in VisualStudio Code, with Dotnet5 API angular MVC application

for me it was the generated `main.js` file in `wwwroot` folder. deleted the folder and ran `ng build --prod` again and got a new one with current code.